# MySQL: Get count of all rows matched, along with with result set

Tags: mysql

If you look at [my fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c11ab5/1), you can see that I am running a query and trying to get the count of all rows matched, along with the result set.

I want to get the count of *all* rows that were matched, though I may only return a result set of a fraction of them since I'm doing pagination with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

What's wrong with my query?

```
SELECT item.*, COUNT(item.id) AS _count
FROM item
JOIN user
    ON user.username = "Lansana"
    AND user.deleted_at IS NULL
JOIN user_item
    ON user_item.item_id = item.id
    AND user_item.user_id = user.id
    AND user_item.deleted_at IS NULL
WHERE item.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY item.id
ORDER BY item.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is turn your query in an aggregation query.  In most databases (and the most recent versions of MySQL), you would get an error -- because the `select` has unaggregated columns not in the `group by`.

All aggregation queries with no `group by` return exactly one row.

If you want the number of rows, then use `CALC_FOUND_ROWS` (documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS item.* 
. . . ;
```

Then issue another query:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: Found rows isn't what I'm looking for. I want to get the count of *all* rows that were matched, though I may only return a result set of a fraction of them since I'm doing pagination with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. Edited question to be more clear.

Comment: @Lansana . . . Then `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is *exactly* what you are looking for.  Did you read the documentation?  "The second SELECT returns a number indicating how many rows the first SELECT would have returned had it been written without the LIMIT clause."